# ‘query’ does not exist in type ‘QueryFn’ | angularfire2 |

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

is not assignable to parameter of type ‘QueryFn’.Object literal may only specify known properties, and ‘query’ does not exist in type ‘QueryFn’.

[image]

```
this.af.list('/viajes-list/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'idchofer',
        equalTo: 2
      }
    })
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like the below code and refer this [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md)

```
this.af.list('/viajes-list/', ref => ref.orderByChild('idchofer').equalTo(2))
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

Comment: How do I get the data back? the subscribe does not work out error

Comment: What similar syntax of code will be there in firebase for the following query?? "select * from table where id = '2' OR '4' ";